# c++ a fixed sized priority queue to store k-nearest neighbors

Tags: c++, stl, priority-queue, knn

I am implementing k nearest neighbor search in a tree data structure. I store the results in a priority queue, which will automatically sort the elements in a ascending order, and so the first k elements are the results. The priority_queue container in STL is really not a good option here because it support only a few functions such as push(), pop(), top(), size() empty(), etc. A big problem here is that when searching the whole tree, I need to visit a lot of nodes, and using push() will make the priority queue longer and longer, which will increase time cost for later operations. What I really want is a fixed-length priority queue, so when push() a new element into the queue, some elements with larger values will be automatically deleted. How can I implement this? Or is there any standard container I can use? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about using `std::set`? It stores elements in order, and if it grows above `k` elements you can just remove the largest one (in constant time). Each insertion is O(log k).

Comment: That works much better and solved my problems, Sir! Thank you very much!

Comment: Note: this doesn't allow duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

One way with `priority_queue` but changing the ordering (ascending to descending), and if it grows above `k` elements, remove the top element (which is the farther).

Comment: can i ask one more question regarding priority_queue? Since there is no direct method of getting an element from a priority_queue (i mean we can not do it using queue[i] way), is it good to define a vector or array and dump the elements of the priority_queue to this vector, so that we can easily access the elements?

Comment: @daydayup: `priority_queue` doesn't provide access to its content, you have to pop each element. An alternative is to use directly `std::push_heap`/`std::pop_heap` on an `vector` (to avoid the copy).